# Console not shown on Mac OS X app bundle?

Tags: macos

I've created a console application for Mac OS X, and packaged it up into an application bundle. The application bundle seems to execute and run fine, but Mac OS X isn't showing a console display when it is run.

How can I instruct Mac OS X to show a console window while the application is running?

Comment: Can you package up a command line utility as an app bundle?  How does that work?

Comment: What do you mean by a "console window"? A Terminal window, or something else?

Comment: @Monolo A terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you launch the command line app, but if it is just as a Unix process, then you won't get a Terminal window.

Terminal is a real OS X GUI app, so you would need to launch Terminal from your app and tell it to execute your unix program or use some Launch Services equivalent of

```
$open -a Terminal <program name>
```

As a cheap solution, you can execute the command line above in an [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).